# South vs Southern - difference?

Tags: adjectives, geography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is the use of “north” more appropriate than “northern” and vice versa?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27584/when-is-the-use-of-north-more-appropriate-than-northern-and-vice-versa)

Are there any differences in meanings of South vs Southern, North vs Northern, and so on, when used in to modify a location? If yes, what is it?

One example I can think of is that South America normally means the area where Brazil, Argentina, etc. are, and Southern America normally means the southern part of the US. Is this only a special case or is this an instance of a more generalized rule?

Comment: *Southern America* is rarely used to refer to the American South, IMO. It's usually *the American South*, or more simply, *the South*. In a more geographic sense, it's *the southern part of the US* or *southern US*.

Comment: Related: [When is the use of “north” more appropriate than “northern” and vice versa?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27584/when-is-the-use-of-north-more-appropriate-than-northern-and-vice-versa) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the use case you're looking at, you use *South* when you want a noun form, either on its own, or as part of an established compound noun.  You use *Southern* when you need an adjective to modify the name of a place, but where *South Foo* is not an established phrase.  Some examples:

- *South Africa* - Here, an established name for a particular place.  If you said *Southern Africa* you could really mean any reasonable area containing the southern end of the African continent.
- *West Memphis* (or *East St. Louis*) - These are the names of established cities just across the Mississipi River from the more famous cities lacking the cardinal direction.  Note that if you said *Western Memphis* or *Eastern St. Louis*, you would be referring to portions of the main city, itself.
- *The North Shore* - This is an established place name in at least a few places, but note that if it isn't, you would use *the northern shore of Foo*.

Comment: *South Africa* is a country, just saying :) Largely concur with your argument, but there are some exceptions. For instance, *Northern Ireland* does not follow the same logic...

Comment: @Jimi Oke - Right, *South Africa* is an established place's name is sort of what I was going after.  Northern Ireland is a great counter-example though.  I wonder if the naming has been influenced by the strife associated with it (e.g. those who wanted it to remain part of the Republic of Ireland may have wanted to simply treat it as the northern area, rather than a distinct place)

Comment: @Jimi Oke - Oh, I see, I said *South Africa* was a region.  I guess I meant *place*, but it's a good catch.  Will edit.

Comment: @Dusty (per your second comment): exactly what I was after :)

Comment: @Dusty (per your first comment): Agreed. It's interesting how these North[ern]/South[ern] namings are decided on! South Sudan is/was going through the same dilemma. *Western Sahara* is also another interesting example. But indeed, *North Foo/South Foo* is the standard.

Comment: @Dusty - Northern Ireland is definitely political between the half that think it's a country (ulster) and the half that think it's the northern part of Ireland. West Germany used to be similar - official German usage was 'Western Germany' to emphasise that it was only half of a greater country that was temporarily divided.

Comment: @Martin Beckett - Does anyone refer to it as *North Ireland*?

Comment: @Dusty - no, the nearest is people in Eire wanting to be gracious calling it 'the north'