# "North" or "Northern" as adjective

Tags: word-choice, differences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is the use of “north” more appropriate than “northern” and vice versa?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27584/when-is-the-use-of-north-more-appropriate-than-northern-and-vice-versa)

Is there any rule when to use *North* and when *Northern* as adjective?

I thought that it's *North* for entirety of the thing located in the North and *Northern* for only the northern part of a bigger whole, but this is not always the case: *Northern Hemisphere, Ohio Northern University, North Seattle Community College, North Africa.*

Comment: the question linked to doesn't answer when is North preferred as adjective. Why not Northern Seattle Community College?

Comment: The terms you're asking about are simply names chosen by institutions. They could have just as easily chosen The University of Northern Ohio, The University Located Centrally in the Northern part of Ohio - next to the big tree, or any other number of combinations of words. When it comes to the names of institutions, it's 100% marketing. For correct usage of capitalization, see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's largely (but not completely) arbitrary whether to use, say, *North* or *Northern* as a modifier.

In contexts where *North X* is a well-recognised "entity" (*North Korea, North America,* for example), there's a very strong tendency to use the shorter *North*.

In contexts where there's more the sense of an "ad-hoc" distinction being made between the geographically-distinct areas within *"X"*, the tendency is to use the more overtly adjectival form. Thus we're likely to refer to *"Northern Alpine slopes"*, or *Northern England*, because these areas are still fundamentally perceived as being part of *"the Alpine slopes"*, or *"England"*, rather than autonomous entities.

But as been mentioned in comments, in many cases (names of institutions, for example), it's entirely a matter for the people in charge what they call themselves. They may have reasons for their choice which have little or no relevance to how others see things.

Answer (score 2):

It is arbitrary.  Typically somebody thinks which sounds best in a particular case and then others copy them.  But as an adjective there is no rule.

*South Africa* is a country, part of the region of *southern Africa*: one of its provinces is called *Western Cape*, but could easily have been called *West Cape* and is in Afrikaans (*Wes-Kaap*).

Answer (score 0):

*North* is an area; *northern* is originating from, or having the characteristics of, the north.

So, North England or North Seattle are areas, in the north of England or Seattle respectively. Lancashire Hotpot or Black Pudding are northern English foods, as they originate from North England, and "By 'eck, it's proper grand..." is a northern English comment, as it is characteristic of the north.

For your college, if it has one campus in north Seattle, it is North Seattle Community College. If it has more than one campus, you could call it Northern (because its characteristic is being in the north)Seattle Community College to distinguish it from the Southern/Eastern/Western Seattle Community College Campuses.

Comment: I'm not satisfied with your explanation of why the campus uses "North".  Why is it the University of North Alabama, but the University of Northern Colorado?  Eastern Connecticut State University, but East Tennessee State University?  University of West Georgia, but Western Oregon University?  Seems these examples might be cases where either term could be used?  (Don't worry, I won't even bother asking you to explain the name of [this institution](http://www.eastwest.edu/new/index.php/about/history)...)